# Android MediaCodec video/avc Decoder

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I've read everything I can get my hands on here and everywhere else about decoding a video stream using MediaCodec.  I have met with some success and find myself stuck.  I get video on the surface after a few buffers of input but it is garbled with green blobs randomly.
I first pass the SPS and PPS NALUs individually.  After the PPS I get a response of Output Buffers Changed from dequeuOutputBuffer().
The first handful of NALUs after that dequeueOutputBuffer requests result in -1 return value (not understood).
After a handful of this I get Output Format Changed.  This is when I start to get video.
I dumped the format values and found that the only thing changing is the MIME to video/raw
I tried to use this to set the format up front but MediaCodec throws errors.

Here is my Code:

```
File extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File media = new File(extStorage,"video.h264");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(media));
codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 480, 384);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 480 * 384);
format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "video/avc");
codec.configure(format, videoSurface, null, 0);
codec.start();
//Get arrays of our codec buffers
ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
long timeoutUs = 3000;
BYTES_READ = new byte[1500];
while (in.read(BYTES_READ) != -1) {
  for ( byte b : BYTES_READ) {
  nalUnit.write(b);
  if ( String.format("%02X", b).equals("00") && hdrIndex < 3 ) {
  NAL_HEADER[hdrIndex++]=b;
  } else if ( hdrIndex == 3 && String.format("%02X", b).equals("01") ) {
  NAL_HEADER[hdrIndex++]=b;
  } else if ( hdrIndex == 4 ) {
  NAL_HEADER[hdrIndex++]=b;
  if (nalUnitIndxS == -1) {
  nalUnitIndxS=0;
  nalUnitIndxE=nalUnit.size()-5;
  } else if (nalUnitIndxS >= 0){
  nalUnitIndxE=nalUnit.size()-5;
  }
  if (nalUnitIndxE > 0 ) {
  Log.d(TAG,"Attempting to write NAL unit to codec buffer... SIZE:"+nalUnit.size()+" IndxStart: "+nalUnitIndxS+"  IndxEnd: "+nalUnitIndxE);
Log.d(TAG,"NAL Unit Type: "+String.format("%02X", nalUnit.toByteArray()[4]));
/*
* Get an input buffer
*/
int inputBufferIndex=-1;
for ( int x = 0; x < 4; x++ ) {
inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeoutUs);
if ( inputBufferIndex >= 0 ) {
break;
} else {
Thread.sleep(250);
}
}
if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
// fill inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex] with valid data
long presentationTimeUs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
int nalUnitLen=nalUnitIndxE-nalUnitIndxS;
inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex].put(nalUnit.toByteArray(), nalUnitIndxS, nalUnitLen);
if ( configPacket ) {
Log.d(TAG,"Writing payload as configuration to codec...");
codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex,0,nalUnitLen,presentationTimeUs,MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);
} else {
codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex,0,nalUnitLen,presentationTimeUs,0);
//deQueue the Output Buffer
MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufInfo, timeoutUs);
if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
Log.d(TAG,"OutputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.");
codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex,true);
} else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
Log.d(TAG,"Output Buffers Changed!");
outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
} else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
// Subsequent data will conform to new format.
Log.d(TAG,"Output Format Changed! Updating format...");
format = codec.getOutputFormat();
} else {
Log.w(TAG,"Did not understand OutputBuffer Index Response: "+outputBufferIndex);
}
}
nalUnit.reset();
nalUnit.write(NAL_HEADER,0,5);
nalUnitIndxS=0;
nalUnitIndxE=0;
} else {
Log.w(TAG, "We did not get a buffer!");
}
}
} else {
hdrIndex=0;
}
if ( hdrIndex == 5 && ( String.format("%02X", NAL_HEADER[4]).equals("21") || String.format("%02X", NAL_HEADER[4]).equals("25") ) ) {
configPacket=false;
hdrIndex=0;
} else if ( hdrIndex == 5 ){
configPacket=true;
hdrIndex=0;
}
}
}
Log.d(TAG,"Cleaning up Codec and Socket....");
codec.stop();
codec.release();
```

Comment: If you're seeing glitchy video then my guess would be that some of the packets aren't being extracted quite right (does the behavior change if you alter the size of BYTES_READ?).  Note that depending on the codec you may have to submit 4-5 buffers before you see anything on the output.

Comment: If you display the video stream on a surface, why do you read the content from the output buffer of decoder? I mean the surface will read and display it automatically. And I'm wondering if the green blob is just caused by the reading.

Comment: Does the input ByteBuffer `inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex]` have position set to 0? Perhaps `clear()` needs to be called before `put`.